# Pixelated UIButton edges

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I'm using Storyboard and I created a `UIButton` with a custom image.

I have a problem that the edges of the button are pixelated:

Image:

[image]

Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: The image size and imageview size should be exact same.

Comment: You must have the all size images `@1x`, `@2x` and `@3x` images. Or you can use vector image. and imageview/button's size should be `@1x` image.

Comment: @AshishKakkad Thank you!

Comment: @AshishKakkad Do you know any software for Mac that can convert an image to all the required sizes?

Comment: @AshishKakkad Do you know its name?

Comment: @FS.O Generally it is given by the designer. else you can use [Prepo](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/prepo/id476533227?mt=12) or a tool for Xcode [RTImageAssets](https://github.com/rickytan/RTImageAssets).

Comment: you can use mac preview app to increase the image size @FS.O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 Ways to create this button.

1. You can add plus character in the default button. Give the red background and corner radius.
2. Add all assets like @1x, @2x and @3x in the folder.

   You can prepare assets by using [Prepo](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/prepo/id476533227?mt=12) or a tool for Xcode [RTImageAssets](https://github.com/rickytan/RTImageAssets) Or any-other tool that fits your requirement.
3. Use vector image as asset. Article : [Use of vectors in Xcode](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/)

Comment: I'm trying to do it using RTImageAssets but it seems it generates the same size for all sizes (I put a 1000X1000 image on the 3x and it generates the same size for 1x and 2x), and the button is still pixelated

Comment: I made is bigger and then decreased it. What size should it be (3x)

Comment: 3x (retina which will be used in iPhone 6 Plus) is maximum size for button. 1x = 3x/2 and 2x = 1x * 2. This is the concept now just put the image size that you want.

Comment: So if the UIButton size on the storyboard is 45x45, the 3x image should be 45x45?

Comment: @FS.O Good. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing this in the simulator in scaled mode, the image may appear to be blurry. Viewing this in 100%scaling mode may remove this effect.
But if you are having this problem in a device, then there is a problem with your image assets. Using adobe photoshop you can create images according iOS guidelines.
This link can help you 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Comment: What is the sizes I need for a regular UIButton?